# Do I need to close my FileOutputStreams?

Tags: java, android, stream

I have inlined temporary `FileOutputStream` that I am not able to explicitly close.

Is that a problem?

```
File raw = new File(uri.getPath());
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());

File compressedPicture = MEUtils.createTemporaryFile(getPackageName());
// see here
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
                  mObjectiveDefinitionForTakingPictureResult.getQuality(),
                  new FileOutputStream(compressedPicture));

JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = (JpegImageMetadata) Sanselan.getMetadata(raw);
TiffImageMetadata exif = jpegMetadata.getExif();
TiffOutputSet outputSet = exif.getOutputSet();
outputSet.setGPSInDegrees(app.locationListener.getLongitude(),
                          app.locationListener.getLatitude());

File compressedPictureWithMetadata = MEUtils.createTemporaryFile(getPackageName());
// see here
OutputStream compressedPictureWithMetadataOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(compressedPictureWithMetadata));
new ExifRewriter().updateExifMetadataLossless(compressedPicture,
                                              compressedPictureWithMetadataOutputStream,
                                              outputSet);
```

### EDIT

It seems that `BufferedOutputStream` can conveniently wrap a `FileOutputStream`, directly by inline it in the constructor: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html

Comment: in C# I would ask if you have tried a `using` block.  but I don't know enough about Java.  does it have something similar?  that would automatically close the connection when it is finished using it.

Comment: @Malachi There's no Java equivalent, sadly.

Comment: I guess you would have to Debug the program and see if the Garbage collection grabs that connection and throws it away.  it's never really a good idea to leave a connection open.  if the garbage collection grabs it when the application is finished with it you should be fine, but if this is a long running application that will call this code many times before the connection gets closed it will cause issues.  I would find a way to close the connection or put it into the ExifRewriter(assuming this is something you wrote) Method

Comment: @mikeTheLiar In Java 7, there's a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block. Too bad it's still not as automatic as C++, where the destructor gets called as soon as a variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do.

While the garbage collector does close your `FileOutputStream` (by calling `finalize`), it is not a good idea to rely on it because it runs unpredictably.

This means that if you do not close your streams explicitly, you may run into a [limit on the number of simultaneously open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473182/is-there-a-limiltation-of-simultaneous-filestreams) or into inability to open a file until you close the previous stream to it (on Windows) or into unpredictable file content if you open several streams to the same file (on Unix).

Comment: The garbage collector only frees the memory occupied bu the object being gc'd. It does not close the file descriptor the OS assigned.

Comment: @bowmore: It depends on the GC. Are you sure Java's does not?

Comment: `FileInputStream`'s `finalize()` will try to close the file, but the garbage collector itself does not attempt to free any resources other than memory.

Comment: @bowmore: but the GC will call `finalize`, right?

Comment: Not guaranteed to. From Effective Java (2nd ed;) : 'It is entirely possible, even likely, that a program terminates without executing
finalizers on some objects that are no longer reachable. '

Comment: @bowmore: that is irrelevant

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11151/discussion-between-bowmore-and-sds)